# Geo cluster - quorum vs Booth

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, drbd

I configured a geo cluster using pacemaker and DRBD. The cluster has 3 different nodes, *each node is in a different geographic location*. The locations are pretty close to one another and the communication between them is fast enough for our requirements (around 80MB/s).

I have one master node, one slave node and the third node is an arbitrator. I use aws route 53 fail over dns record to do fail over between the nodes in the different sites.

A fail over will happen from the master to the slave only if the slave has quorum, thus ensuring it has communication to the outside world.

I have read that using booth is advised to perform fail over between clusters/nodes in different locations - but having a quorum between different geographic locations seems to work very well.

I want to emphasize that I don't have a cluster of clusters - it is a single cluster, with each node in a different geo location.

My question is - why do I need booth in my case? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: booth is used to do geo clustering, if for some reason you have a problem with your cluster, the resources can migrates to other cluster = disaster recovery

Comment: @c4f4t0r I know what booth is, what it does and how to use it. My question is - if in my case as described above - do I really need booth? Or is my multi site cluster with 3 nodes and quorum of 2 nodes is enough?

Comment: you need to describe what you mean with multi site cluster, if you are talking about mutil-zones or multi-regiones, in anycase, if the cluster goes down, for human error or bug in the software with a single cluster with nodes distributed in multiple sites, your service will be down, if don't care about the single cluster down, you don't need booth, if you want to have a disaster recovery, you need booth, distribute your nodes in multiple sites, you will not save in case of cluster problem

Comment: When I say multi site, I mean different server farms in different geographic locations. I don't use aws for hosting so the zone/region terminology is irrelevant for this discussion . I have a single cluster, made up of 3 nodes, each node in a different site. The DR is between two master/slave nodes (active/passive)

Comment: Setup multinodes in multi data centers is not DR, because they part of the same cluster, many things could happen that can bring down the whole cluster.

Comment: Such as? I would be happy if you could provide an example.
Each node runs all services in a single server (the same node) so the DR is actually between two nodes. Thanks

Comment: you need to change a parameter in the cluster configuration communication layer(corosync), I would to repeat that, if your nodes are distribute in many locations, that are sharing something, the same network, the same software, A disaster recover is to have a secondary cluster, You are using pacemaker, but is the same with many clusters, you could have many case that can bring down your cluster, clusterlabs site can help you with this